# How i define a default value?

Tags: php, laravel, migration

How to fix this?

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'note' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `people` (`name`, `email`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Luis, luis@hotmail.com, 2, 2021-08-09 15:03:07, 2021-08-09 15:03:07))

[image: My migration:]

I've already tried to set a default value, but I believe I'm not doing it right

Comment: make it nullable `$table->longText('note')->nullable()->after('email');`

Comment: Always share your codes in syntax highlighted text format, DO NOT SHARE IMAGE!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-modifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either decide to have a default `null` value or some default other string.

For default null value:

```php
Schema::table('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->longText('note')->nullable()->after('email');
});
```

Any other default value should be:

```php
Schema::table('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->longText('note')->default('Some Default Value.')->after('email');
});
```